Stall Current vs Nominal Current - which to consider while designing a motor controller
I am working on a motor controller project, and this is the motor spec:
Nominal Voltage: 24V
Nominal Current (max continuous current): 6A
Stall Current: 80 A
The question is which number to focus more on while designing a controller. If it is the nominal current, I could get away with using a monolithic solution like TB67H400ANG chips.
The specs:

But am I right in thinking I will have to focus on the stall current value and design a beefier controller, with a Half-bridge driver and discrete MOSFETs that can handle 80A of current? And if that's the case, since my motors are a bit expensive, would it be a good idea, apart from having capacitors with the power supply, to add a fuse in series making sure the current does not exceed 80A? Or should I use resistors instead? Thanks and any advice would be great.
